# torch.cuda.is_available() is false for cuda 11.7,after checking the version of pytorch and set environment path

Tags: pytorch

My cuda version is `11.7` 
My torch version is `2.0.0+cu117`  
I also checked the environment path:

```
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/cuda/lib64:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH 
export PATH=/usr/local/cuda/bin:$PATH
```

But still remains false...
Want help